# Need the detail or description of permission.C2D_MESSAGE

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, android-permissions, android-push-notification

In my app, I use the GCM push notification. All sample app for push notification has this two permission. I need to know the reason for this permission. I couldn't find any documentation of `permission.C2D_MESSAGE` permission.

```html
<permission android:name="YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

Comment: Any reason you're still using GCM? It's officially been deprecated and will be removed in just a few more months.

Comment: I can't move to FCM for some reasons of the company. I know it will be removed in 2019